Can Migrations change project into production?
I would like to know if I make changes into my laravel project in localhost (I downloaded the project from the hosting) the project from the hosting also changes
I have been doing some changes into the project as Local, I downloaded the project from the hosting and I made some migrations. I also changed the .env file to connect it into a localhost database, but when I try to run migrations with php artisan migrate the terminal says application is in production, do you really want to procced. I´m not sure about it, its my first time using a project from a hosting

Most likely not... your local project seems to run in production mode, which is probably due to flags in your .env, but to change the production you would need to check in your changes and deploy them, and isn't done coincidentially.

No, the changes will only affect your current environment. You're getting that error because you have APP_ENV set to production in your .env file

since you copied everything from hosting (probably .env too), you might have also copied the actual production keys for your SQL. make sure that you change it to your local keys before doing any migrations. (you might accidently migrate your production)
